# Why won't tidyverse install and how do I fix it?

Tags: tidyverse

```
package �tidyverse� was built under R version 4.0.5Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'dbplyr':

  method         from

  print.tbl_lazy    

  print.tbl_sql     

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’:

package ‘gtable’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it
```

Comment: Does anyone have an idea of how I can fix the issues and be able to use tidyverse

Comment: Did you try updating or re-installing the `gtable` package, as the error suggests. Also try to include your R version, RStudio version, your Operating system (and its version) and also the current versions of relevant packages like `gtable`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Causes of "Error: package '\_\_\_\_\_' was built before 3.0.0: please re-install it" in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987948/causes-of-error-package-was-built-before-3-0-0-please-re-install-it)